# App runs only when running via Xcode, it doesn’t work when I try to run it on device disconnected from Mac

Tags: ios, xcode

I use Xcode 11 beta and running with iPadOS.

The app works perfectly when running via Xcode, but once it’s disconnected from my Mac and I try to open it on I the iPad the app crashes immediately. What should I do to prevent that? Is it possible that this is a beta bug?

I already try to change the run scheme to release in order to catch the error but the app still worked perfectly fine when it was connected to my Mac, and it still crashes when I try to open it on the iPad.

The crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: A2B40D37-80CB-44EC-BDF8-31218AE57CB0
CrashReporter Key:   94955e0a5779727fdfd5897c9de1267cd96a2c20
Hardware Model:      iPad8,5
Process:             ExampleApp [15367]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B7A07E6-AA57-435B-BCF9-DBBAD9BC0276/ExampleApp.app/ExampleApp
Identifier:          com.matanm.ExampleApp
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.matanm.ExampleApp [6447]


Date/Time:           2019-07-01 19:02:41.8674 +0300
Launch Time:         2019-07-01 19:02:41.8078 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.0 (17A5508m)
Release Type:        Beta
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1b2706dcc __exceptionPreprocess + 224
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1b2c27688 objc_exception_throw + 59
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1b25f76c4 +[NSException raise:format:] + 111
3   UIFoundation                    0x1b9a07b5c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 411
4   UIFoundation                    0x1b9a07ed0 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1295
5   UIFoundation                    0x1b99a2d7c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 319
6   UIKitCore                       0x1ba9c6b14 -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 671
7   UIFoundation                    0x1b9a07c9c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 731
8   UIFoundation                    0x1b99a2d7c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 319
9   UIKitCore                       0x1ba1fbbd4 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 175
10  UIFoundation                    0x1b9a07c9c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 731
11  UIFoundation                    0x1b9a07ed0 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1295
12  UIFoundation                    0x1b99a2d7c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 319
13  UIKitCore                       0x1ba1f6ad4 -[NSCoder+ 6904532 (UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsWithSourceSegueTemplate:creator:sender:forKey:] + 491
14  UIKitCore                       0x1ba1f970c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1115
15  UIKitCore                       0x1b9f35e88 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 367
16  UIKitCore                       0x1b9f36930 -[UIViewController loadView] + 179
17  UIKitCore                       0x1b9f36c00 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 187
18  UIKitCore                       0x1b9f372e8 -[UIViewController view] + 31
19  UIKitCore                       0x1b9eb2924 -[UINavigationController preferredContentSize] + 171
20  UIKitCore                       0x1b9e5b53c -[UIPresentationController preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:] + 71
21  UIKitCore                       0x1b9e57754 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 159
22  UIKitCore                       0x1b9e5d688 +[UIPresentationController _scheduleTransition:] + 103
23  UIKitCore                       0x1b9e5751c -[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState] + 1539
24  UIKitCore                       0x1b9e54e3c -[UIPresentationController _presentWithAnimationController:interactionController:target:didEndSelector:] + 983
25  UIKitCore                       0x1ba598868 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 399
26  UIKitCore                       0x1ba598df0 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 319
27  UIKitCore                       0x1ba5a964c -[UIWindow _mainQueue_makeKeyAndVisible] + 51
28  UIKitCore                       0x1ba78dd84 -[UIWindowScene _loadWindowWithStoryboardIfNeeded:] + 643
29  UIKitCore                       0x1ba78dad4 -[UIWindowScene _readySceneForConnection] + 151
30  UIKitCore                       0x1b9ba0d4c +[UIScene _sceneForFBSScene:create:withSession:connectionOptions:] + 959
31  UIKitCore                       0x1ba55d5f8 -[UIApplication _connectUISceneFromFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 991
32  UIKitCore                       0x1ba55d988 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 339
33  UIKitCore                       0x1ba10d990 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 375
34  FrontBoardServices              0x1b4e17b00 -[FBSSceneImpl _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 451
35  FrontBoardServices              0x1b4e4078c __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.174 + 115
36  FrontBoardServices              0x1b4e22fbc -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 239
37  FrontBoardServices              0x1b4e40420 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 343
38  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b2ef0114 _dispatch_client_callout + 19
39  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b2ef2e44 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 251
40  FrontBoardServices              0x1b4e681b8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 47
41  FrontBoardServices              0x1b4e67e64 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 419
42  FrontBoardServices              0x1b4e683e4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 51
43  CoreFoundation                  0x1b26821f4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 27
44  CoreFoundation                  0x1b268217c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 91
45  CoreFoundation                  0x1b26818dc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 183
46  CoreFoundation                  0x1b267c7d0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1067
47  CoreFoundation                  0x1b267c07c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 479
48  GraphicsServices                0x1b184c37c GSEventRunModal + 107
49  UIKitCore                       0x1ba56174c UIApplicationMain + 1939
50  ExampleApp                          0x102cea760 0x102cdc000 + 59232
51  libdyld.dylib                   0x1b2be6964 start + 3


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b2d54f04 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b2f2cc20 pthread_kill + 224
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b2dd4af4 abort + 104
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b2ed13c8 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b2ed15c0 demangling_unexpected_handler+ 5568 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b2c27968 _objc_terminate+ 22888 () + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b2ede634 std::__terminate(void (*)+ 58932 ()) + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b2ede5c0 std::terminate+ 58816 () + 44
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b2ef0128 _dispatch_client_callout + 40
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b2ef2e44 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 252
10  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001b4e681b8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48
11  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001b4e67e64 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 420
12  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001b4e683e4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 52
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b26821f4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b268217c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 92
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b26818dc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 184
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b267c7d0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1068
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b267c07c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
18  GraphicsServices                0x00000001b184c37c GSEventRunModal + 108
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001ba56174c UIApplicationMain + 1940
20  ExampleApp                          0x0000000102cea760 0x102cdc000 + 59232
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001b2be6964 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b2f33c3c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b2f33c3c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b2f33c3c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b2f33c3c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b2d32bc0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b2d31fdc mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b2681a78 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 220
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b267c938 __CFRunLoopRun + 1428
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b267c07c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
5   Foundation                      0x00000001b21ea774 -[NSRunLoop+ 34676 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232
6   Foundation                      0x00000001b21ea64c -[NSRunLoop+ 34380 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001ba5f97d4 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 156
8   Foundation                      0x00000001b21e9404 -[NSThread main] + 40
9   Foundation                      0x00000001b2323488 __NSThread__start__ + 852
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b2f2bc4c _pthread_start + 132
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b2f33c50 thread_start + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b2f33c3c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000002809fcdb7
    x4: 0x00000001b2ee17a8   x5: 0x000000016d1224f0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000500
    x8: 0x0000000000000800   x9: 0x0000000000000407  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x000000000000001e  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001dca022f0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000103015840  x21: 0x0000000000000407  x22: 0x0000000103015920  x23: 0x0000000103015920
   x24: 0x0000000000001f03  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x000000016d122cb0  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016d122450   lr: 0x00000001b2f2cc20
    sp: 0x000000016d122420   pc: 0x00000001b2d54f04 cpsr: 0x00000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Comment: what preprocessor flags did you set?

Comment: I didn’t add any preprocessors flags

Comment: did you try to debug wirelessly?

Comment: Yes, it works when it’s connected to Xcode wirelessly.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: It was a bug in that beta, it’s working now.